# Changing the text which appear when clicking on an annotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

i use MapKit to locate user and i want to personnalize the text which appear when the user click on the annotation, the default text is **current location**

here is my code :

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{
    MKPinAnnotationView *annView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentLoc"];

    // annotation color
    [annView setPinColor:MKPinAnnotationColorGreen];
    //annotation  Animation
    [annView setAnimatesDrop:YES];

    [annView setCanShowCallout:YES];

    return annView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use MKAnnotationView rather than MKPinAnnotationView.  MKAnnotationView has a property called annotation which has a property called title, so:

```
annview.annotation.title = @"title";
```

I haven't tested doing it this way exactly, the usual way to do it is to make a custom class that implements the MKAnnotation protocol and then add instances of that class to the map.

Comment: hey, thx it worked but gived me warning : -setTitle:' not found in protocol(s), i think i should make MKAnnotation protocol

Comment: The "title" property of MKAnnotation class is readonly. You cannot set the title in this way, you have to subclass MKAnnotation and provide to the annotationView your MKAnnotation instance.